# Grails: Inject FixtureLoader into Specification

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, fixtures, spock

Does anyone know how to inject the grails FixtureLoader into a test?  I've tried everything, but to no avail. The first thing I've tried was doing this in my tests.

```
def fixtureLoader
```

or
   FixtureLoader fixtureLoader

Intellij shows that it is "spring injected" with the little leaf, but no luck.  Then I tried adding this to my spring/resources./groovy file.

```
beans = {
    fixtureLoader(FixtureLoader)
}
```

Wrong again.

The closest I have gotten to was adding this to my tests so that it looks like this.

```
@TestMixin(FixtureLoader)
class SomeControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
```

but that didn't work either.  However, when debugging, I saw a $fixtureLoader variable that was initialized.  One of the side problems I noticed when debugging was that the FixtureLoader class requires a "grailsApplication" while being initialized.  What was passed to it during the test was null.

Any help on this injecting conundrum is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Integration spec inside test/integration should inherit IntegrationSpec. Second, DI should work in integration spec. Third, instantiate controller and then set injected fixtureLoader to it. FYI, don't need the entry in resources.groovy.

Comment: @dmahapatro You were right.  After making the changes you prescribed, I still had problem.  This was because the IntegrationSpec was being run with a JUnit configuration in Intellij.  The trick was to create a new Grails configuration, and set the commandline variable to like so "grails test-app integration: dummygrailsapp.SomeControllerIntegrationSpec"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test should pass in Grails 2.3.7.

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader

class SampleIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def fixtureLoader

    void "test something"() {
        expect:
            fixtureLoader instanceof FixtureLoader
    }
}
```